# minify-maven-plugin minifying html and xml files also

Tags: javascript, maven, minify

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>minify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                        <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                        <webappSourceDir>WebContent</webappSourceDir>
                        <cssSourceDir>/</cssSourceDir>
                        <jsSourceDir>/</jsSourceDir>
                        <nosuffix>false</nosuffix>

                        <webappTargetDir>${project.build.directory}/minify</webappTargetDir>
                        <cssSourceIncludes>
                            <cssSourceInclude>**</cssSourceInclude>
                        </cssSourceIncludes>
                        <cssSourceExcludes>
                            <cssSourceExclude>**/*.min.css</cssSourceExclude>
                        </cssSourceExcludes>
                        <jsSourceIncludes>
                            <jsSourceInclude>**</jsSourceInclude>
                        </jsSourceIncludes>
                        <jsSourceExcludes>
                            <jsSourceExclude>**/*.min.js</jsSourceExclude>
                        </jsSourceExcludes>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I am using maven-minify-plugin to minify js and css files and added above code in pom.xml.Now this works fine but it tries to minufy all files including xml and html files.
How can I stop minifying xml and html and other files?

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example of how to minify only css in a project. Probably your problem is about paths like **/*..

Hope this helps:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>minify-css</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                        <jsEngine>closure</jsEngine>
                        <cssSourceDir>WEB-INF/assets/stylesheets</cssSourceDir>
                        <cssSourceFiles>
                            <cssSourceFile>jquery-ui.css</cssSourceFile>
                            <cssSourceFile>leaflet.css</cssSourceFile>
                            <cssSourceFile>app.css</cssSourceFile>
                        </cssSourceFiles>
                        <cssFinalFile>style.css</cssFinalFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
          </executions>
     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alien01, changing the lines `<cssSourceInclude>**</cssSourceInclude>` to `<cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>` and `<jsSourceInclude>**</jsSourceInclude>` to `<jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>` should fix it.
Please let me know if it worked.